Is there a way to calculate the average distance of multiple points in R?
I have a dataset of 100 coordinates (in long/lat format) and have been able to map them using ggmap; they have different categories (ex. grocery stores versus gas stations).
I now need to calculate the average distance between the coordinates for each category (as to compare the spatial distribution between grocery stores versus gas stations); how can I do this in R?
Have seen lots of answers regarding calculating the distance between two spatial points, but looking for something that takes into account the distribution of these multiple points and averaging them all. Is this something that would make more sense to do in a different language than R?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The easiest way would be calculate distance by themself and calculate mean value of it. Using sf::st_distance() you can calculate distance between points, like:
(p are the point coordinates for shops in Trzebnica, Poland, taken from OpenStreetMap)
bb <- osmdata::getbb("Trzebnica, dolnośląskie")
s <- osmdata::opq(bb, timeout = 25*60) |>
  osmdata::add_osm_feature(key =  "shop") |>
  osmdata::osmdata_sf()

p <- s$osm_points |>
  subset(!is.na(shop))

nrow(p)
#> [1] 36

sf::st_distance(p[1:3, ,], p[1:3, ,])
#> Units: [m]
#>          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
#> [1,]   0.0000  85.6592 219.1792
#> [2,]  85.6592   0.0000 134.9195
#> [3,] 219.1792 134.9195   0.0000

sf::st_distance() calculates the distance between all/each point and creates symmetrical matrix. We should remove 0's from it to calculate mean:
m <- sf::st_distance(p, p)
m[m == units::as_units(0, "m")] <- NA
m[1:3, 1:3]
#> Units: [m]
#>          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
#> [1,]       NA  85.6592 219.1792
#> [2,]  85.6592       NA 134.9195
#> [3,] 219.1792 134.9195       NA

m |>
  mean(na.rm = TRUE)
#> 1018.374 [m]

